# Connecting MySQL Database to NetBeans Error

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I have a problem when running my code in NetBeans in order to see if mySQL is connected. This is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection connect = null;

    try{
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tUsers?autoReconnect=true/useSSL=TRUE","root","password");
        if(connect!=null)
        {
        System.out.println("Connected");
        }
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("RIP");
    }
  }
}
```

when I run it prints out "RIP". When I debugged it line by line, it went from the "connect = DriverManager.getConnection..." to "System.out.println("RIP"), and when I look at the "Exception e" it says "e = (java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException) java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Malformed database URL, failed to parse the connection string near '=TRUE'."

Now, why is that?????

Comment: I would suggest starting with [Connection URL Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-jdbc-url-format.html)

Comment: I'm wondering if `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tUsers?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=true` would work better

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add 
`Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` .

Also, make sure everything in `Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection (String url, String user, String password);` are set correctly.

From the url format in your code, it's like you are trying to get direct connect to specific table `tUsers` in your database. And I dont think that would work. Correct me if I'm wrong whether it's literally your database name or not.

Because the basic [url format](https://www.javatpoint.com/example-to-connect-to-the-mysql-database) i know, should be like `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourDBname` .

If you already set the url correctly as is written in your post, then the code is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
    Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tUsers?autoReconnect=true/useSSL=TRUE","root","password");
    if(connect!=null)
    {
    System.out.println("Connected");
    }
}catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("RIP");
}}}
```

Hope that could do the work.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but when I added the "Class.forName..." it said that it is unnecessary, and the "tUsers" is a scheme not a table.